# Problems displaying a textbox when character collides with an NPC

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I'm having a problem displaying a textbox to the screen when my character's collision box collides with that of a certain NPC's collision box.

This first section of code is part of the module file I created where I created assets for the game to use. This is where I created my text-box object to be used in the main file.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

class stuff:
    def __init__(self, Surface):
        self.surface = Surface
        self.readyfornextbox = False
        self.textboxlist = []

    def textbox(self, textinput, textcolor,location): #extra is basically asking whether or not the programmer wants t oclose
        self.readyfornextbox = True #Checks if player is going to be clicking for next text box to appear on screen
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)

        text = self.font.render(textinput, 1, (255, 0, 0))
        self.textboxlist.append([text,location])


    def ready(self, ready):
        if self.textboxlist:
            self.textboxlist.remove(self.textboxlist[0])

        if(not self.textboxlist):
            self.readyfornextbox=False

    def draw_textbox(self):
        if(self.readyfornextbox==True):
            pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, (0, 255,0), self.textboxlist[0][1])
            self.surface.blit(self.textboxlist[0][0], ((self.textboxlist[0][1].x + 25), (self.textboxlist[0][1].y + 25)))
```

This next section of code is from the main file of the game itself. This is where I am calling to draw the text-box to the screen when the conditional of the player's collision box colliding with that of the NPC's collision box is met. I am calling it outside of the main game loop.

```
if PC_ColBox.colliderect(OM_ColBox):
    blah.textbox("Hello there, young man", (255, 0, 0), bottom)
```

For some reason, the text-box is not being displayed to the screen. I have used the same conditional statement before without problem to create a boundary between the player and NPC that stops the player from overlapping onto the NPC. So I don't think the conditional is the problem. Also, when the text-box is called by itself without the conditional statement, it displays just fine.

Thank you in advance for the help.

**EDIT**
As requested by two users, I will be pasting the whole main file of code below. Thank you guys so much for trying to help by the way :)

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import os, time, random
import essentials
import pyganim


#bleh = random.randint(2, 30)
#print(bleh)

bottom = pygame.Rect(120, 450, 760, 100)

middle = pygame.Rect(120, 250, 760, 100)

top = pygame.Rect(120, 50, 760, 100)

FOV = Rect(701, 1570, 1000, 600)

pygame.init()
Axis_Change_x = 0
Axis_Change_y = 0
Change = 0
x_Axis_Move = False
y_Axis_Move = False
CamMoving = False
CamSpeed = 0

UP = False
RIGHT = False
DOWN = False
LEFT = False

BG = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))
BG.fill((0, 0, 0))
blah=essentials.stuff(BG)
BG1 = pygame.image.load("firstbackground.png")
##blah.textbox("This...", (255, 0, 0), top)
##blah.textbox("is a...", (255, 0, 0), middle)
##blah.textbox("test...", (255, 0, 0), bottom)

#blah.textbox("CHECK!", (255, 0, 0))


#Evil Old Man
OM_Stand_Front = pygame.image.load("oldman.png")
OM_ColBox = Rect(520, 220, 25, 61)

#Player Character
PC_WalkF1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("PC", "WalkF1.png"))
PC_WalkF2 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("PC", "WalkF2.png"))
PC_WalkB1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("PC", "WalkB1.png"))
PC_WalkB2 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("PC", "WalkB2.png"))
PC_WalkL1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("PC", "WalkL1.png"))
PC_WalkL2 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("PC", "WalkL2.png"))
PC_WalkR1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("PC", "WalkR1.png"))
PC_WalkR2 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("PC", "WalkR2.png"))
PC_ColBox = Rect(500, 400, 67, 79)

#Cyclops
C_WalkF1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Monster", "monsterWalkF1.png"))
C_WalkF2 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Monster", "monsterWalkF2.png"))
C_WalkB1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Monster", "monsterWalkB1.png"))
C_WalkB2 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Monster", "monsterWalkB2.png"))
C_WalkL1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Monster", "monsterWalkL1.png"))
C_WalkL2 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Monster", "monsterWalkL2.png"))
C_WalkR1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Monster", "monsterWalkR1.png"))
C_WalkR2 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Monster", "monsterWalkR2.png"))

if PC_ColBox.colliderect(OM_ColBox):
    blah.textbox("Hello there, young man", (255, 0, 0), bottom)


while True: #The main game loop
    CurrentTime = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    #blah.textbox("This is a test 2232323", (255, 0, 0))


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_d:
                Change = 0
                CamSpeed = 0
                if not event.key == K_a and not event.key == K_w:
                    UP = True
                    LEFT = True
                if not event.key == K_a and not event.key == K_s:
                    DOWN = True
                    LEFT = True

                if not event.key == K_a:
                    LEFT = True
                    DOWN = False
                    UP = False
                else:
                    UP = False
                    RIGHT = False
                    DOWN = False
                    LEFT = False

            if event.key == K_a:
                Change = 0
                CamSpeed = 0
                if not event.key == K_d and not event.key == K_w:
                    UP = True
                    RIGHT = True
                if not event.key == K_d and not event.key == K_s:
                    DOWN = True
                    RIGHT = True

                if not event.key == K_d:
                    RIGHT = True
                    UP = False
                    DOWN = False
                    LEFT = False
                else:
                    UP = False
                    RIGHT = False
                    DOWN = False
                    LEFT = False

            if event.key == K_w:
                Change = 9
                CamSpeed = 0
                if not event.key == K_s:
                    DOWN = True
                    Change = 9
                else:
                    DOWN = False

            if event.key == K_s:
                Change = 0
                CamSpeed = 0
                if not event.key == K_w:
                    UP = True
                else:
                    UP = False
                    CamSpeed = 0






        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()


            if (event.key == K_d and not event.key == K_a and not event.key == K_w and not event.key == K_s):
                #BG.blit(AL, WizardHitBox, AL_right_stand)
                Change = 9
                CamSpeed = 9
                UP = False
                RIGHT = True
                DOWN = False
                LEFT = False


            elif (event.key == K_a and not event.key == K_w and not event.key == K_s and not event.key == K_d):
                Change = 9
                CamSpeed = 9
                UP = False
                RIGHT = False
                DOWN = False
                LEFT = True
                Axis_Change_x = 9

            elif (event.key == K_w and not event.key == K_a and not event.key == K_s and not event.key == K_d):
                Change = 9
                CamSpeed = 9
                UP = True
                RIGHT = False
                DOWN = False
                LEFT = False

            elif (event.key == K_s and not event.key == K_a and not event.key == K_w and not event.key == K_d):
                Change = 9
                CamSpeed = 9
                UP = False
                RIGHT = False
                DOWN = True
                LEFT = False
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                blah.ready(not blah.readyfornextbox)

        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    if RIGHT == True:
        PC_ColBox.x += Change
        if PC_ColBox.colliderect(OM_ColBox):
            PC_ColBox.x -= Change



    if LEFT == True:
        PC_ColBox.x -= Change
        if PC_ColBox.colliderect(OM_ColBox):
            PC_ColBox.x += Change

    if UP == True:
        PC_ColBox.y -= Change
        if PC_ColBox.colliderect(OM_ColBox):
            PC_ColBox.y += Change

    if DOWN == True:
        PC_ColBox.y += Change
        if PC_ColBox.colliderect(OM_ColBox):
            PC_ColBox.y -= Change

    #BG.fill((0, 0, 0))
    BG.blit(BG1, Rect(0,0,1000,800), FOV)
    BG.blit(OM_Stand_Front, (500, 200))
    BG.blit(PC_WalkF1, (PC_ColBox.x, PC_ColBox.y))
    blah.draw_textbox()

    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.wait(10)
```

**Edit 2** As suggested by Junuxx, I put the conditional with the calling of the text-box inside the main loop right before I have the PC move away if it collides with the NPC. As shown below. The text-box is unfortunately still not showing up even with this arrangement.

```
if PC_ColBox.colliderect(OM_ColBox):
    blah.textbox("Hello there, young man", (255, 0, 0), bottom)

if RIGHT == True:
    PC_ColBox.x += Change
    if PC_ColBox.colliderect(OM_ColBox):
        PC_ColBox.x -= Change

if LEFT == True:
    PC_ColBox.x -= Change
    if PC_ColBox.colliderect(OM_ColBox):
        PC_ColBox.x += Change
```

Comment: If you've already stopped the rects from overlapping (presumably by moving one), they will no longer overlap in this test. Can you show the main loop?

Comment: Which conditional are you talking about in the last paragraph? The one calling `colliderect` or the one in `draw_textbox()`?

Comment: I am talking about the conditional calling `colliderecct` .

Comment: Can you edit your post to (at least) include the code where you used that conditional before and how you create that boundary? Because it sounds like otus was right, but it's hard to tell if we can't see the code.

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually call [`pygame.display.update()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) after blitting the textbox? This is needed to show any changes to the screen!

**Edit:**
After seeing more of your code, it appears you should move the collision detection inside your main loop. Right now you only check for collisions once, right at the start *before* you enter the main loop.

And of course, considering their starting locations, it's not possible for the two characters to collide before they have started moving.

Should work if you move it to right before the `if RIGHT == True` conditional.

```
if PC_ColBox.colliderect(OM_ColBox):
    blah.textbox("Hello there, young man", (255, 0, 0), bottom)


if RIGHT == True:
    PC_ColBox.x += Change
    if PC_ColBox.colliderect(OM_ColBox):
        PC_ColBox.x -= Change
```

Comment: Yes, that is being called at the end of all the code on the main file.

Comment: I guess we could use a little more context from the main file, as @otus already requested.

Comment: Should I include the whole main file? Will I have to add four spaces to each and every single line one at a time?

Comment: You can paste the code, select it all and click the "{ }" button, that formats it as code for you.

Comment: Yep, that explained the problem. See my edited answer :)

Comment: Hmmm, I tried doing that and I'm still having the problem :/ Where exactly in the main loop should I put it?

Comment: Move it to the part right before where you move the PC away if it collides. Won't work if you put it after that.

Comment: I'm going to edit the original post showing where I put it. I am putting it right before the PC moves away if it collides with the NPC. Still no luck unfortunately.

Comment: Try printing the rects each cycle to see what's going on? i.e. add `print(PC_ColBox, OM_ColBox)` right before you check if they collide?

Comment: I included what you suggested, and everything seems to be in order, but it's still not displaying the text box when the player character and NPC collide. :/ I know someone who might be able to help and I'm going to ask them and see what they say about what I should. I'll keep this post updated though. Thanks for your help so far, Junuxx.